# Actionbar and statusbar height

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-statusbar, android-api-levels

Can someone tell me what is the actionbar height, statusbar height and APILevel of Samsung Galaxy S6 and Samsung Galaxy Note 5.

Comment: http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php

Comment: I checked this link. I couldn't find the value for Galaxy S6. It's resolution is 1440x2560 px, but there is no such information in this site. Also I couldn't find the value for Note 5.

Comment: About API level, you can get such information on the wikipedia or Samsung's official site. About heights of ActionBar and status bar, you can get them programatically (please search stackoverflow).